# What are the primary theoretical difficulties with adding ML-style modules to Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ocaml, sml, ml, type-systems

It is well known that Haskell-style typeclasses and ML-style modules offer different mechanisms for specifying *interfaces*. They are (possibly) equivalent in power, but in practice each has their own benefits and drawbacks.

Since I'm a bit of an inclusionist when it comes to language features, my question is this: What are the primary theoretical difficulties with adding ML-style modules to Haskell? I'm interested in answers along the following lines:

- What existing type system features interact poorly with ML-style modules? (An example of poor interaction is GADT and functional dependencies, even though fundeps are technically equivalent to associated types!)
- What things have to be given up on the compiler end in order to compile ML-style modules?
- How do ML style modules interact with type inference?

Related reading:

- [Robert Harper’s post that provoked this question](http://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/04/16/modules-matter-most/)
- [Discussion on Haskell Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/grq99/ml_modules_matter_most/)

Comment: Thanks for asking this.  I *love* ML functors, it's the one thing I really miss in Haskell.

Comment: Why would you want functional dependencies in a module system? As far as I can tell all functional dependencies do is control inference/implicit instantiation, which modules don't really try to do.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The main place to do the comparison is,

- [ML Modules and Haskell Type Classes: A Constructive Comparison](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~chak/papers/WC08.html). Stefan Wehr and Manuel M.T. Chakravarty. In Proceedings of The Sixth ASIAN Symposium on Programming Languages and Systems - APLAS 2008, Springer-Verlag, LNCS, 2008.
- [Modular Type Classes](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~chak/papers/DHC07.html). Derek Dreyer, Robert Harper, and Manuel M. T. Chakravarty. In Proceedings of The 34th Annual ACM SIGPLAN - SIGACT Symposium on Principles of Programming Languages, ACM Press, 2007.
- [First class modules for Haskell](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/67016/first_class_modules.pdf), Mark Shields and Simon Peyton Jones. Submitted to the Ninth International Conference on Foundations of Object-Oriented Languages (FOOL 9), Portland, Oregon. 20 pages. Oct 2001.

I'm not actually aware of any theoretical issues -- at least, concrete proposals have been made (and implemented in prototypes) -- the Shields and PJ paper have a lot of the details. The implementation burden however, is non-trivial.

Comment: In 2014, it's probably worth updating with a reference to [Backpack](http://plv.mpi-sws.org/backpack/) which is trying to bring something like an ML-style module system to GHC.

Comment: [No HKT](http://archive.is/itQtX#selection-48019.0-48021.4) in core ML (∉MixML) for first 2 cited papers that implement typeclasses as modules. [_§7 Conclusion_](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/first_class_modules.pdf#page=12) of third cited paper concludes that _§3 Abstract Modules and Existentials_’s [existentials instead of](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/5121#comment-84650) dependent sums breaks [encapsulation](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/5121#comment-84486). [Discussion](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/5121#comment-84248) with examples.

Comment: @Lambdageek as of Nov 2017, the author of this question Edward Z. Yang has been [the active maintainer of Backpack](http://archive.is/https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Backpack) since at least Aug 2017. For example, see his [blog post](http://blog.ezyang.com/2014/09/open-type-families-are-not-modular/) on anti-modularity of typeclasses when construed as an algebra. And his [blog post](http://blog.ezyang.com/2014/08/whats-a-module-system-good-for-anyway/#comment-7357) on why we need modules. Backpack is partially based on MixML, which afaik allows/has HKT in the core language.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think there's any big theoretical problems.  You'd have to make a decision about applicative functors or not.  Applicative is probably more in the Haskell style.
But I think any attempt at adding ML style modules to Haskell will be grotesque because the overlap between modules and classes; there will be two ways of doing many things.

Comment: you don't have to add, you could replace

Answer (score 8):

Simon PJ has argued that ML style modules have a poor power/cost ratio, that they are hard to implement. See SPJ's [slides from POPL 2003](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/haskell-retrospective/HaskellRetrospective-2.pdf) (towards the end). He also calls for a design which has a better power/cost ration but I'm unaware of any such proposal.

Comment: The question asked for theoretical difficulties but the issues you cite are just the beliefs of one person. You might consider OCaml's delimited overloading to be a higher power/cost ratio use of modules.

Comment: The slides are just SPJ's opinion, but it's a common one — also because the metatheory of ML modules is very tricky. And Derek Dreyer gives to it enough credit to react to it by presenting a different metatheory — the great "F-ing Modules" (http://www.mpi-sws.org/~dreyer/papers/f-ing/journal.pdf). After reading it, I couldn't reproduce their formal translation, but I could translate most (all?) use of SML modules to plain Fomega.